# Can I disable selection for specific elements?

Tags: figma

My frame contains an element filling the entire frame area (in the back).

Every time I span a selection, that element is part of it, and I have to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click to unselect it.

Can I make it unselectable or inactive somehow?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I'm not a figma user, but maybe look to see if there is a way to lock the layer. Most vector image editors have a lock you can apply to layers/objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ctrl+L` or `Cmd+L` keys to lock and unlock an object in Figma.